# How to create string buffer to iterate over it and convert value of type 'String.CharacterView.Index' to expected argument type 'Int'?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa

ObjC code:

```
#pragma mark - bookNameFromString
+(NSString *) bookNameFromString:(NSString *)string{

NSMutableArray *newLineArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSUInteger length = [string length];
unichar buffer[length+1];
[string getCharacters:buffer range:NSMakeRange(0, length)];

NSInteger a = 0;
do {
    a = a+ 1;
    char current = buffer[a];
    if (current == '\n') {
        [newLineArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:a]];
        break;
    }

} while (a <= length);

NSString *bookName  = nil;
if (newLineArray.count > 0 && newLineArray[0] != 0) {
    bookName = [string substringToIndex:[newLineArray[0]integerValue]];
}

return bookName;
}
```

In Swift:
**While converting to swift**

1. How to create string buffer as done in objC.
2. While appending value to array, there is an error: Cannot convert value of type 'String.CharacterView.Index' to expected argument type 'Int'

   ```
    // MARK: - bookNameFromString
   func bookNameFromString(string:String) ->String {

   let toFind:Character = "\n"
   var newLineArray:[Int] = []
   let lengthOfString = string.characters.count

   var a = 0
   repeat{
       a = a + 1
       if let index = string.characters.indexOf(toFind) {
           newLineArray.append(index) */ERROR: Cannot convert value of type 'String.CharacterView.Index' to expected argument type 'Int'/*
           break
       }
   }while a < lengthOfString

   print(newLineArray)

   var bookName:String
   if newLineArray.count > 0 && newLineArray[0] != 0{
       bookName = string.substringToIndex(string.startIndex.advancedBy(newLineArray[0]))
   }

   return bookName
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an *attempt of an approach* without buffers and checking single characters

```
func bookNameFromString(string : String) -> String?
{
  // separate string by linefeed character
  let array = string.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
  // if string is empty or there is none or one linefeed - exit
  guard array.count > 1 else { return nil }
  // define a startindex which is 1 if the string starts with linefeed
  let startIndex = array[0].isEmpty ? 1 : 0
  // if there is no linefeed left - exit
  guard array.count > startIndex + 1 else { return nil }
  return  startIndex == 1 ?  "\n" + array[startIndex] : array[startIndex]
}


bookNameFromString("")                // -> nil
bookNameFromString("\n")              // -> nil
bookNameFromString("\n\n")            // -> \n
bookNameFromString("Hello")           // -> nil
bookNameFromString("\nHello")         // -> nil
bookNameFromString("Hello\n")         // -> Hello
bookNameFromString("Hello\nWorld")    // -> Hello
bookNameFromString("\nHello\n")       // -> \nHello
bookNameFromString("\nHello\nWorld")  // -> \nHello
```